# C - set cookie in http header?

Tags: c, http, cookies

I would like to know if it is possible to add a short cookie in the http header of a request that would not be erased over the session.

It would be nice to prevent a loadbalancer to do ssl termination but just reading th cookie and do the logic accordingly.

## -> This is for theoretical purposes only

Digging into all the rfc is a huge undertaking so if someone knows.. That would be nice :)
Thanks

Comment: You are aware of that an ip-header and a http-header are different things, aren't you?

Comment: yes, I know i set up a wrong tag :)

Comment: After all, forget about that I have another plan :)

Comment: Only the server can create cookies and govern their lifetime. A client cannot create its own cookies that a server did not send to the client first. And even then, cookies have nothing to do with SSL. There is no way for a client to send arbitrary data to the server and have that data be persisted over time. Cookies are meant for servers to persist data, not clients.

Comment: What EXACTLY are you trying to prevent?  Please explain with an example.